# 'unable to retrieve list' in Dashboard Designer

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence, dashboard-designer, data-connections

After setting up the Performance Point Application and the BI Center I tried to create some data connections to a specific sharepoint site.
It works without errors on the "Project-task-list" and the "Issues-tracking-list". Unfortunately I also have a tasklist to which it's impossible to connect to and I receive an 'unable to retrieve list' error.
The only difference with the two other lists is that I have two workflows running on it with impersonation steps.

I can select the list I want but when I test the connection it says 'Unable to retrieve list' although all security settings are the same for that site.

Can anyone help me with this?